How to prove the de Rham complex of sheaves of modules.
My question: 
Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $\mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ be a homomorphism of sheaves of rings. Denote $d: \mathcal{B} \rightarrow \Omega_{\mathcal{B} / \mathcal{A}}$ the module of differentials with its universal $\mathcal{A}$-derivation. Let $\Omega_{\mathcal{B} / \mathcal{A}}^{i} = \wedge_{\mathcal{B}}^{i}(\Omega_{\mathcal{B} / \mathcal{A}})$ for $i \geq 0$ be the $i$th exterior power. We define the de Rham complex of $\mathcal{B}$ over $\mathcal{A}$ is the unique complex
$$\Omega_{\mathcal{B} / \mathcal{A}}^{0} \rightarrow \Omega_{\mathcal{B} / \mathcal{A}}^{1} \rightarrow \Omega_{\mathcal{B} / \mathcal{A}}^{2} \rightarrow \dots$$
And $d_{i}: \Omega_{\mathcal{B} / \mathcal{A}}^{i} \rightarrow \Omega_{\mathcal{B} / \mathcal{A}}^{i + 1}$ is given by $d_{i}(b_{0}d(b_{1}) \wedge \dots d(b_{i})) = d(b_{o}) \wedge d(b_{1}) \wedge \dots \wedge d(b_{i})$ with $b_{0}, \dots b_{I} \in \mathcal{B}(U)$. My question is, how to prove that $d_{i}$ exists uniquely and is well defined. 
My attempt: 
Since the algebraic de Rham complex is clear, I would like to consider the stalk $(\Omega_{\mathcal{B} / \mathcal{A}}^{i})_{x} = \Omega_{\mathcal{B}_{x} / \mathcal{A}_{x}}^{i}$. However, due to the involvement of exterior powers, sheafification, and other operations, it is difficult for me to consider the homomorphism of stalks from the germ. Is there any simple method or detailed proof? Any conclusion or reference book is very helpful.

The beginning of your question reads identical to the treatment in the Stacks project. Did you read a bit further? They define the complex as the sheafification of a complex of presheaves, which is given by $$U \mapsto \Omega^\bullet_{\mathcal B(U) / \mathcal A(U)}.$$ So if you want to consider stalks, just take the stalks of the presheaves.

I have also read here, but I am not very clear about the elements in the stalks of this presheaf. Can you explain them in detail

The stalks of a presheaf are the same as the stalks of its sheafification. So for every $\omega \in (\Omega^k_{\mathcal B / \mathcal A})x$ there is an open $U$, such that $\omega$ is represented by $\omega_U \in \Omega^k{\mathcal B(U) / \mathcal A(U)}$. So $d(\omega_U)$ is a well-defined $(k+1)$-form on $U$, and it represents $d\omega$ at  $x$.

I have another question, how to prove that the morphism on the stalks are unique and well-defined can deduce that the overall morphism is unique and well-defined.

I'm not sure how you get well-definedness from the stalks. But you don't need to, since the morphisms are defined via sheafification of morphisms on presheaves. The uniqueness I have already answered in your other question ;-)
